# What are the missing 7 numbers?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Below a sequence of numbers is stated, I'm looking for the 7 missing natural numbers which should replace the 7 x's. Counting will give you information which can be neither positive nor negative.

> 02305230790701047230xxxxxxx

A hint to get you started:

"A number always starts with a 0, but a 0 isn't always the start of a number."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The rule is:

> 23 is the 9th prime number.
>
>  523 is the 99th prime number.
>
>  7907 is the 999th prime number.
>
>  104723 is the 9999th prime number.

The missing 7 digits are:

> **1299689**, the 99999th prime number.